# How to create a map chart with GeoIP mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-configuration, geoip

I'm fairly new to ELK (7.10), and I would like to know how to create a map chart using GeoIP mapping.

I already have logs parsed and one field is "remote_ip" which I want to view on a map chart.

I've seen lots of instructions on how to do this but most are out of date and do not apply to my version which is 7.10. I'm using filebeats/logstash/kibana/elasticsearch.

Could someone show me the high level steps required to do this? Or point me to a detailed guide appropriate to my version? I have no idea how to begin.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming those IP addresses are public so you can geocode them. Since your logs are already indexed, you now need to geocode them. Here is how to do it.

First, you need to modify your mapping to add a `geo_point` field, like this:

```
PUT your-index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "remote_location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }
}
```

Once you've added that new field to your mapping, you can update your index to geocode the IP addresses. For that, you first need to create an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) with the [`geoip` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geoip-processor.html):

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/geoip
{
  "description" : "Geocode IP address",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "geoip" : {
        "field" : "remote_ip",
        "target_field": "remote_location"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Once this ingest pipeline is created you can use it to update your index using the [`_update_by_query` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) like this:

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query?pipeline=geoip
```

Once the update is over, you can go into Kibana, create an index pattern and then go to Analytics > Maps and create your map.

Comment: I create a field called location. The update_by_query failed with messages like this. 

`    {
            "index": "testlogs",
            "type": "_doc",
            "id": "5gkMLXgBUmsGuOK23OnC",
            "cause": {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "failed to parse field [location] of type [geo_point]",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "parse_exception",
                    "reason": "field must be either [lat], [lon] or [geohash]"
                }
            },
            "status": 400
        }`

Comment: Can you show a sample document as well as your current index mapping